# Where has Gradle gone in Android Studio 3.5 on Windows 10?

Tags: android, gradle

I've just installed Android Studio 3.5 but I can't find Gradle any more. In Android Studio 3.4 and below, Gradle was located in

```
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-xxx/bin/gradle
```

In Android Studio 3.5 I'm not able to find the "gradle" executable any longer. Where is it now?